# A pokemon stadium consists of 2 cat pokemon, 4 flying pokemon, 5 water pokemon, 12 fire pokemon and one psychic pokemon

Tags: combinatorics

How many distinguishable arrangements can be made if:

a) The 2 cat pokemon must come first and the psychic pokemon last?

- What I tried: 24P2*22P4*18P5*13P12*1P1 (This didn't give me the right answer)

b) The 2 cat pokemon must come first and the psychic pokemon last, however 4 flying pokemon have to be beside each other?

Please explain how you got your answer I want to learn thanks:)

Comment: Some hints: if a group of size $n$ must be at the front/back, then perform your calculations without them and then consider adding them back, recalling that there are multiple ways to arrange these $n$. If a group of size $n$ must be together in the permutation, consider them as a single element and perform your calculations, remembering to multiply the result by the number of distinct ways you could arrange that group of size $n$.

Comment: @Orangutango i tried: 24P2 + 4*5*12 + 23P1 .. If that's what you mean?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that _cat_ is not a valid pokemon type, so the answer should be $0$.

Comment: @ Tomas: Meowth Is a cat type pokemon LOL.

Comment: You should go for Magikarp.

Comment: The shape of Meowth is a cat, the type however is _Normal_, as you can see [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Meowth_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). However, we should move this discussion to pokemon.SE.

Comment: Okay guy I just need the answer for the question

Answer (score 3):

Are pokemons of the same type distinguishable? If not, then for the first question the solution is as follows:

- total number of positions to fill equals 2 + 4 + 5 + 12 + 1 = 24
- you have the unique way to fill in the first two positions - by the two cat pokemon, and their order doesn't matter.
- you have the unique way to fill in the last position, that is, by the psychic pokemon.
- for the other 24 - 2 - 1 = 21 positions you have $A = \frac{21!}{4!\cdot 5! \cdot 12!}$ ways.

So there are $1\cdot A \cdot 1 = A$ ways.

The second question goes as follows. Since your four flying pokemon must be together (and are indistinguishable, hence it doesn't matter how they are arranged with respect to each other), you may consider them as a single object. So now you have not 24 objects and 24 positions, but in fact 21 object and 21 position. You deal with 2 cat pokemon and the psych pokemon as in the previous case, and for the rest 17  pokemon there are $\frac{17!}{5!\cdot 12!}$ different arrangements. Hope that helps...

Comment: I get error when I try to compute that..

Comment: @MethodManX: It seems like you know the correct answer. Maybe you should tell us that, so that we can conclude, whether pokemon of the same type are distinguishable for the purpose of this task.

Comment: The answer is 37035180 for a

Comment: @Tomas that's the answer

Comment: @MethodManX: $\frac{21!}{4!5!12!}=37035180$, so Alex's answer is fine. (+1)

Comment: @Tomas : then why I keep getting Error on my calculator?

Comment: @MethodManX: Most certainly because you did not operate your calculator well or your calculator is not capable of computing factorials. Try an other [calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=21!%2F(4!5!12!)).

Comment: @MethodManX: Indeed, MethodManX, don't try to compute factorials, they could be too large to handle for an ordinary calculator. Instead, simply cancel whatever you can in the fraction: $\frac{21!}{4!5!12!} = \frac{12!13\cdot14\cdot ... \cdot 21}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot12!} = \frac{13\cdot ... \cdot21}{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5} = ...$ and so on.

Comment: The answer for b is 111384 but with ur method I get 6188 hmm

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, I'm sorry, that's because after dealing with the 2 cat pokemon and one psychic pokemon out of 21 total, I somehow got 17 pockemon left (that's a mistake!) instead of 21 - 3 = 18 pokemon... So the correct answer had to be $\frac{18!}{1!5!12!}$ which is correct... Here we simply use the general rule. See, if you have $n$ distinct objects, there are $n!$ distinct arrangements of these objects. If there are $k_1$ objects of type $1$, ..., $k_m$ objects of type $m$, and $k_1+...+k_m = n$, then these $n$ objects can be arranged in $\frac{n!}{k_1!...k_m!}$ different ways.

Comment: These $k_i!$ are there to make sure that you don't take into account the rearrangements of elements of the $i$-th type among each other (since these elements are indistinguishable).